# Visiting website as mobile device from desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I use Google Chrome as my main browser on Windows 7.

Can you make some websites believe that you are browsing their site on a mobile device, when I'm actually browsing on Google Chrome desktop?  The purpose is to generate a mobile-device optimized page, which I can then send to my friends. For example, I do facebook on desktop, but when I see an interesting post, I'd like to circulate it as a mobile-optimized link (m.facebook.com/*****), because most of my friends use smartphones. But I want this to happen with only some social media sites - facebook, twitter, etc. For all other sites, I want regular display on my monitor.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the "User-Agent" switches for chrome.

The way a mobile page is detected (normally) is via the user-agent setting, which can be arbitrarily set by a browser.  Try [This search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/user%20agent%20switcher) to find one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to press F12 to open up the Dev tools in Chrome.  In the bottom right corner there is a little gear symbol. Click this symbol to pull up the settings.  In the Overrides tab, check the boxes for Enable and User agent.  The User Agent drop down has a long list of devices it can emulate for you.  Not that only the tab currently opened when you pressed F12 will be affected by the changes you make here.  And those changes only apply while the Dev Tools pop up is open.